# Ember input - default value

Tags: ember.js

How do I get the default value of input to be "laptop" when I have the valueBinding, which sets the input balue to null? (value is set when there is no valueBinding)

```
{{input value="laptop" valueBinding="subject"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `subject` to "laptop", setting both `value` and `valueBinding` creates ambiguity, since they both are the same thing.

```
{{input value=subject}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cotabe/1/edit